# Train Test Split with same index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I want the rows with the same index to exist in the same set - either Train or Test, but not both. How can I make this happen in sklearn? For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6], 'B': random.sample(range(10, 100), 12)})
df.set_index('A', inplace = True)
```

I want to achieve:

Train set with indices 1, 3, 5, 6
Test set with indices 2, 4

How can I also ensure this with GridSearchCV?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set them as `'group'`.  Most splitters in sklearn support a param named `groups` in them, which can be set to do what you want

Example:

You can use [GroupKFold](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GroupKFold.html) or [GroupShuffleSplit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GroupShuffleSplit.html):

```
group_kfold = GroupKFold(n_splits=3)
for train_index, test_index in group_kfold.split(df, groups=df.index):
    print("Train", df.iloc[train_index].index)
    print("Test", df.iloc[test_index].index)

Output: 
('Train', Int64Index([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4], dtype='int64', name=u'A'))
('Test', Int64Index([5, 6, 6, 6], dtype='int64', name=u'A'))

('Train', Int64Index([2, 2, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6], dtype='int64', name=u'A'))
('Test', Int64Index([1, 1, 1, 3], dtype='int64', name=u'A'))

('Train', Int64Index([1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 6, 6, 6], dtype='int64', name=u'A'))
('Test', Int64Index([2, 2, 4, 4], dtype='int64', name=u'A'))
```

You can see that the last train test split matches your requirement. All folds will have data which be either train or test, but not both.

Comment: Is this also applicable for GridSearchCV?

Comment: @infinite-rotations Yes you can supply this as `cv` param to GridSearchCV